# Strange issues discovered while using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- react -->
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <!-- babel -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel">
      class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = { text: "Hello,World" }
          this.titleRef = React.createRef()
        }
        changeText() {
          // Get node information through ref
          // Print output before setState. => `<h2>5555</h2>`
          console.log(this.titleRef.current)
          // {text:"Hello,World"}
          console.log(this.state)           
          this.setState((state) => {
            return { text: "5555" }
          })
        }
        render() {
          const { text } = this.state
          return (
            <div>
              <h2 ref={this.titleRef}>{text}</h2>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  this.changeText()
                }}
              >
                change text
              </button>
            </div>
          )
        }
      }
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root"))
      root.render(<App />)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the method changeText, I expected the first console.log output to be <h2> Hello,World</h2>, because it's before the setState, and the state data hasn't changed yet. Therefore, I thought the DOM still contained <h2> Hello,World</h2>. However, the actual output was <h2>5555</h2>. I'm wondering what happened?

The change of DOM seems to happen before setState, which is different from my understanding. I must have misunderstood something.

Comment: `this.titleRef.current` is a reference to the element, not a snapshot of it. When you read the reference (in the console) it has changed to 5555. If you want to take a snapshot of the element before it updates use something like `this.titleRef.current.outerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

(I had to add this as an answer, though I'm not sure it's good enough to qualify as one, and I'll need a little help from a more experience member to improve this.)

But it looks as though there is some kind of race condition going on...
I imagine that this is because getting the value of `this.titleRef.current` (which is from the physical DOM) is very costly

I converted your code to a snippet, but look at the screenshot below. It clearly shows the console *inside* the snippet as having the "correct value" for `this.titleRef.current`, but *outside* the snippet (the main browser console) it shows the "incorrect value" for `this.titleRef.current`.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- react -->
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <!-- babel -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel">
      class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = { text: "Hello,World" }
          this.titleRef = React.createRef()
        }
        changeText() {
          // Get node information through ref
          // Print output before setState. => `<h2>5555</h2>`
          console.log(this.titleRef.current)
          // {text:"Hello,World"}
          console.log(this.state)           
          this.setState((state) => {
            return { text: "5555" }
          })
        }
        render() {
          const { text } = this.state
          return (
            <div>
              <h2 ref={this.titleRef}>{text}</h2>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  this.changeText()
                }}
              >
                change text
              </button>
            </div>
          )
        }
      }
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root"))
      root.render(<App />)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

I would like to understand more as to why you want the value of `this.titleRef.current` at any given moment, particularly right before a state update...